# Sharepoint html element naming conventions, by Sharepoint Controls

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

A few times I've attempted to customize a SP2007 page using css, html, or javascript in Sharepoint Designer; however, in Sharepoint Designer I am not able to get direct access to the desired elements since they are generated by a Sharepoint Control (such as a  web part or dataview) and appear only AFTER  the page is rendered in the browser. I use use IE's F12 to tracked the element I wish to change. Then I can see an identifer such as name or id I can use in my javascript or css.

Example 1: SP2007 generates "name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_ba9196a9_2842_4607_b048_9a443cb4def5$ff2_1$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" for an input text box. I use that name to manipulate the text box as I desire.

Example 2: SP2007 generates "id=zz6_menu" for the "Welcome"  text which I use to get the users full name.

So far this has worked out fine. Am I tempting fate?

Can someone refer me to a reference that discusses how these names and other Sharepoint Control element identifiers are generated?

Are they stable? Can I count on them to be the same provided the application I develop with my version of SP isn't updated to a later version of SP? And even if that case I'm thinking I can simply update to the identifiers created by the newer version of SP.

Is this a good practice? Any other comments?

All responses are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is based on ASP.NET and that's why the Ids are automatically genereated.

cf this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX).
You should not use them to identify elements on css or js.

> Do not write code that references controls using the value of the
>   generated UniqueID property. You can treat the UniqueID property as a
>   handle (for example, by passing it to a process), but you should not
>   rely on it having a specific structure.

In my opinion, the best way is to rely on the css classes because they are not automatically generated and should not change a lot.

Anyway, if you upgrade to SP2010 or 2013, lot of your modifications won't work anymore because the structure and css changed...